# AWS CodeDeploy Failure

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, github, aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy a lambda function through CodeDeploy. I have everything set up except my AppSpec file. Since I am deploying a Lambda and not an EC2 instance, I believe that my AppSpec file should be something like this (JSON).

```
{
"version": 0.0,
"Resources": [{
    "myLambdaFunction": {
        "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
        "Properties": {
            "Name": "myLambdaFunction",
            "Alias": "myLambdaFunctionAlias",
            "CurrentVersion": "1",
            "TargetVersion": "2"
        }
    }
}],
"Hooks": [{
        "BeforeAllowTraffic": "LambdaFunctionToValidateBeforeTrafficShift"
  },
  {
        "AfterAllowTraffic": "LambdaFunctionToValidateAfterTrafficShift"
    }
]
}
```

However, when I run "deploy" with this AppSpec, it fails. I am not sure where to look for the information to fill these fields. Is it on my local machine or on AWS somewhere? Or should I use different logic for CodeDeploy Lambda deployment? My end goal is to tie my GitHub mono repo through CodeDeploy and Lambda so it can be deployed across multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're looking for. There will be no useful information on your local machine because you're doing a Lambda deployment with CodeDeploy. I would start in the CodeDeploy console for more information - it should include information as to why your deployment failed. Next, you should look in the Lambda console and CloudWatch Logs to get more information.